# WIX installer for VSTO Word Template for Word 2013 not working correctly

Tags: ms-word, wix, windows-installer, vsto

I developped a VSTO based Word Template and a WIX based installer for it. 
In general the installer works fine, except on Windows 8.1 with Office 2013 (32Bit).
For som unknown reason Office 2013(32Bit) is installed at "C:\Program Files" and the related registry key is pointing to it correctly. 
During execution of the msi package for the Word Template, the registry key seems to be modified as shown in logfile of msiexec:

```
MSI (c) (18:98) [09:10:34:954]: WIN64DUALFOLDERS: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\' will substitute 17 characters in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office15\WINWORD.EXE' folder path. (mask argument = 0, the folder pair's iSwapAttrib member = 0).
```

As a consequence Winword.exe is not found and the installer stops.
I'm using this WIX Code to check whether Word 2010 or newer is installed:

```
<Property Id="WORDEXEVERSION"
          Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="RegSearch_WORDEXE"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe"
                  Type="file">
    <FileSearch Name="WINWORD.EXE"
                MinVersion="14.0.0.0" />
  </RegistrySearch>
</Property>
<Condition Message="Word 2010 or newer is required."><![CDATA[Installed OR WORDEXEVERSION]]></Condition>
```

On other machines with Win 8.1 and Office 2013(32Bit) where Office is installed to "C:\Program Files (x86)" everything works fine.
Does anyone have an idea why Office 2013 could have been installed to the obviously wrong folder or how to make msiexec behave as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The user might have forced the install to go there, that may be possible, or the actual system may have done an in-place upgrade to a 64-bit OS and so the stuff in Program Files will stay there.

What's the purpose of the detection? To see if Word is installed? I ask because I seem to remember that templates have their own folder somewhere and that's where you'd install your template.